# How to access other property value of a document in the schema validate function?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to access the name property value into the password property while doing validation. Can you help me out? I tried this code but obviously name was not defined in the scope, hence was getting an error.
I want to prevent the user from entering their name in the password section...

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        lowercase:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        lowercase:true,
        validate(value){
            if(!validator.isEmail(value))
            {
                throw new Error('Email not valid!')
            }
        }
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        validate(value){
            if(value.length<6||value.length>16)
            {
                throw new Error('Password should be of lenght ranging 6 to 16 characters')
            }
            **if(validator.contains(value,*name*))
            {
                throw new Error('Password should not contain your Name in it')
            }**

        }
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('users',userSchema)
```

Comment: this is not related, but I think the `default` field of date should be `Date.now` not `Date.now()`. Using `Date.now()`, you will get a constant date value of the time that your node.js server starts, not the time that you create the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your document using `this`. So the name can be accessed by `this.name`

```
...
        validate(value) {
            if (value.length < 6 || value.length > 16) {
                throw new Error('Password should be of length ranging 6 to 16 characters')
            }
            if (validator.contains(value, this.name)) {
                throw new Error('Password should not contain your Name in it')
            }

        }
...
```

Comment: Thanks man. This was my first question on this site and i really found a gem, i believe.